# Error restore Gitlab file: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - backup_information.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I got the below error when I tried to restore a gitlab backup file (gitlab installed on RHEL os) to a Gitlab container. The old gitlab has version: 14.0.1, and the new gitlab is version: gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.0.1-ce.0 (that I pull from dockerhub with the command: docker pull gitlab/gitlab-ce:14.0.1-ce.0 )

Anyone can help ?

```
# gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore 1646342111_gitlab_backup.tar
Unpacking backup ... tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: etc/gitlab/trusted-certs: time stamp 2029-07-18 12:03:32 is 232491039.8501198 s in the future
done
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - backup_information.yml
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:245:in `settings'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:113:in `block in verify_backup_version'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:111:in `chdir'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:111:in `verify_backup_version'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:restore
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Hear is the content of the backup_information.yml in the backup file:

```
:db_version: '20210614143954'
:backup_created_at: 2021-08-23 09:40:38.190516122 +07:00
:gitlab_version: 14.0.1
:tar_version: tar (GNU tar) 1.30
:installation_type: omnibus-gitlab
:skipped:
```